# How to get completed result back after meeting traceback in vscode?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, computer-vision, editor

I am running test part in vs code; it can successfully get the predicted results; however, due to my typo error in calculating AUC, it meets traceback then lost all results including the predicted results;

1. so is there any way to get the predicted results back so that I can go to calculating AUC instead of running testing part again?
2. or in vs code, is there any extension so I can check the typo errors?

Comment: Have you tried `Code Spell Checker`?

Comment: that is a good idea